# What does :: at function name mean?

Tags: c++

I saw code like:

```
using namespace zzzz;

void XX::YY()
{

}
```

how does :: work if you write like that?

Comment: This is C++ code, not Java

Comment: @BalusC That's a rather large edit; you changed his question

Comment: @Michael: really? I just removed "in Java" and changed "what's" by "What does" and "mean". Or has this a different meaning in English?

Comment: @BalusC I meant the "in Java" part; the answer to his original question was "well, that doesn't mean anything, because your example isn't Java at all". I suppose the question makes little sense that way though, so you might as well edit it

Answer (score 7):

It's not Java, it's C++. (The `using namespace` and the `::` is the giveaway).

The `::` is the "scope operator". It's how in C++ you say that `YY` is a member of the class `XX`. Java doesn't need this because methods are always defined within the class they belong to; in C++ you can define them in another file.

Comment: Or YY is a member of the namespace XX. Hard to tell from here.

Comment: It isn't that java doesn't need it because methods are defined in the class they belong to, afterall java has scoping in form of packages too. It's just that java uses . for all scoping instead of having different operators for scope access and member access